# IIS: Images, CSS and Scripts missing

Tags: javascript, css, image, iis, visual-studio-2012

I publish my site using IIS, but got the error `Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions`. I tried adding permissions to IIS_USRS, but my computer (Win7) does not have this user. I right clicked on the folder > security tab > Edit > Advanced and searched but the user is not present.

I then editted the basic settings of the application in IIS and connected as a specific user. It almost worked fine as I did not get the error message `Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions`. The page displayed but no style. The CSS, Image and javascripst files are not loaded. I tried browing to the images by setting each of their paths in the URL. The images exist as I was able to browse, but they do not load with the page.

I opened Controll panel > programs and featured > turn owindows features on or off > Internet Information Services > World wide web services > common http featured and I checked static content. But this did not solve my issue.

Why is this?

how can i fix this please?

Comment: are you running VS with admin priviledges?

Comment: Yes I am. Everything works fine on VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using IIS7 or 7.5:

Open IIS manager > choose your site > IIS Panel > Authentication > Anonymous Authentication: Enabled this and also edit this setting to make sure is using Application Pool Identity.